YKVK has both a nominal and adjectival meaning?
Rabbi Ibn Ezra mentions something intriguing on his commentary of Shemot 6:3. He claims that Ha-Shem's name is sometimes a Noun and sometimes an adjective.
As we know the pronunciation of Ha-Shem's name (Noun) was lost after the destruction of the second temple. However, Ibn Ezra noticed it had an adjectival meaning.
Any thoughts on what it could possibly be?

To say phrases like "God powers"

It would have to be related to either the root הוה or היה.

The distinction Ibn Ezra is making (which he explains at length on Shemot 3:15) isn't between nouns and adjectives, but rather between proper names (שם עצם) like "Abraham" and generic names (תואר) like "man." All of the other names of God describe him in some way (e.g. the name אלהים is shared with the angels), but the four-letter name of God is his proper name, referring to God himself.
But he adds that the four-letter name is also sometimes used generically. One of the characteristics of a proper name is that it's never placed in semichut (we can say "the man of X" but not "the Abraham of X"), therefore the semichut construction in ה' צבאות leads him to say that the four-letter name in that phrase is a generic homonym of the proper name (signifying his eternity, independence and dependence of everything else on him).

The explanation for R. Abraham ibn Ezra's comment can come from the two intents (kavanos) that we make for the name YHVH:

היה הוה ויהיה - He was, He is, and He will be, i.e. ever-living - adjective
אדון את הכל - Master of all - noun.

